# TestNG customize test name

Tags: testng

I have a testNg `@Factory` creating several instances of a test class implementing `ITest` interface from the framework, like:

```
public class MyFactory {
    @Factory
    public Object[] tests() {
        return new Object[]{
            new MyTest("first"),
            new MyTest("third"),
            new MyTest("second")
        };
    }
}

public class MyTest implements ITest{

    private String name;

    public MyTest(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Test
    public void execute(){
        System.out.println("Done [" + name + "]");
    }

    @Override
    public String getTestName() {
        return name;
        }
    }
}
```

I need the test name to recognize which test failed (in case).

When I execute the test from the IDE (IntelliJ) the test names are ok, but when executing from maven all tests (in the reports) are named **execute**.

Maven is configured to read a `testng.xml` which reference `MyTestFactory`.

This is the Maven log:

```
 Running TestSuite
...
... TestNG 6.8.9beta by Cédric Beust (cedric@beust.com)
...

Done [third]
Done [second]
Done [first]
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.479 sec - in TestSuite

Results :

Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

The generated report:

[image]

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you share a sample of the maven output?

Comment: What is the case of creating new implementation of ITest?

Comment: @JulienHerr I've updated the question with maven output and the report.

Comment: @RocketRaccoon each test has a json file as input, I want the name of the file as the name of the test

Comment: @rascio Could you try with the latest testng version (6.10)? Yours is really old.

Comment: Have you tried to use DataProvider instead? When using dataprovider testNG will show provided params in report as part of test name

Answer (score 0):

The log output will be available in the html file (under Reporter Output section) using Reporter.log statement. This will help you to identify if any execute method fails[image]

```
 @Test
public void execute(){
    System.out.println("Done [" + name + "]");
    Reporter.log("Test name is : " + name); //Add this line
}
```